# How to sort by a composed field with CrudRepository?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a simple `CrudRepository` that accepts a sortable:

```
class PersonReposiroty extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {
  findAll(Pageable page);
}
```

I want to sort it by the **sum** of two fields:

```
dao.findAll(PageRequest.of(page, size, Sort.by("price1, price2"));
```

Problem: this sorts first by `price1`, then by `price2`. How can I sum it before?

Comment: I think that at that point you'll have to write an explicit query.

Comment: As this will only support sorting by mapped database columns you would then need to create a view with the calculated value and then map it as a field in your Entity using `@SecondaryTable` to pull in the value from the view.

Comment: Would I have to create the view as model bean, or as a database table? I'd prefer a programmatic solution only without having to touch the db...

Comment: No model bean. Database view columns are mapped to Exiting entity using `@SecondaryTable`. Powerful option as you can sort, filter etc in the database as for any other persistent property. Otherwise you'd need to implement your own query logic. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53176186/hibernate-relation-with-aggregation/53177583#53177583

Answer (score 1):

I found out that it **is** actually possible to order by sum, as follows with `querydsl`:

```
private PageRequest pricePageSort() {
    OrderSpecifier<BigDecimal> sort = QPerson.person.price1.add(QPerson.person.price2).asc(); //or .desc()
    return new QPageRequest(pageNumber, pageSize, sort);
}
```

Then use it by:

```
dao.findAll(predicate, pricePageSort());
```

Maybe the `CrudRepository` has to `extends QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Person>` therefore, but I'm using it anyways.