# How to make a paginated dynamic request with a calculated field based on a parameter in Spring JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Given a Slideshow, that contains slides and another table (SeenSlideshow), that stores information about the employees that saw the slideshow.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Wither
@Table(name = "slideshow")
public class Slideshow {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
    private SlideshowStatus status;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "persona", nullable = false)
    private SlideshowPersona persona;

    @Embedded
    private Post post;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "slideshow_id")
    @OrderBy("slide_order asc")
    private List<Slide> slides;

    @Embedded
    private Conclusion conclusion;

    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    private LocalDateTime publishedAt;

    @Transient
    private boolean seen;

    public Slideshow() {
    }

    public Slideshow(Integer id, SlideshowStatus status, SlideshowPersona persona, Post post, Conclusion conclusion, LocalDateTime createdAt, LocalDateTime publishedAt, boolean seen) {
        this.id = id;
        this.status = status;
        this.persona = persona;
        this.post = post;
        this.conclusion = conclusion;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
        this.publishedAt = publishedAt;
        this.seen = seen;
    }
}
```

SeenSlideshow :

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "seen_slideshow")
public class SeenSlideshow {
    @EmbeddedId
    private SeenSlideshowIdentity pk;


    @MapsId("employeeId")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
    private Employee employee;

    @MapsId("slideshowId")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "slideshow_id")
    private Slideshow slideshow;

    public SeenSlideshow() { }

    public SeenSlideshow(Employee employee, Slideshow slideshow) {
        this.pk = SeenSlideshowIdentity.builder()
                                       .employeeId(employee != null ? employee.getId() : null)
                                       .slideshowId(slideshow != null ? slideshow.getId() : null)
                                       .build();
        this.slideshow = slideshow;
        this.employee = employee;
    }
}
```

How can I make a query that :

1. is paginated
2. fill the `seen` transient field of `Slideshow` class
3. allows to be sorted by this `seen`field, based on a given employee (a parameter of the query)
4. fetch the list of slides at the same time
5. has dynamic filters (I usually use either example or specification for that)

I managed to fulfill the first 3 requirements, but not the 4 and 5.

I can use a workaround for the 4, but when I tried to use query by example or specification, it didn't worked because the request I use looks like this :

```
    @Query(
        value =  "select new Slideshow(s.id, s.status, s.persona, s.post, s.conclusion, s.createdAt, s.publishedAt, (SELECT COUNT(ss.pk.slideshowId) > 0 FROM SeenSlideshow ss WHERE s.id = ss.pk.slideshowId and ss.pk.employeeId = :employeeId) as seen ) from Slideshow s",
        countQuery = "select count(s) from Slideshow s"
    )
    Page<Slideshow> findForEmployee(String employeeId, Pageable pageable);
```

As I need a parameter to calculate the `seen`field, I can not add any `Example<Slideshow>` or `Specification<Slideshow>`.

When I add a Specification, Spring JPA considers it as a simple unused parameter, and the dynamic filters are not applied.

How can we make a dynamic query, with a subquery in the select clause ?

Comment: I think you can not include a transient field in your query, since JPA will translate your criteria query into plain sql query and the database is not aware of the field. As far as I know there is no way to apply your workaround to a criteria query or specification. But in case u are willing to use plain Hibernate features you could give the [formula annotation](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-calculated-properties-with-jpa-and-hibernate-formula-annotation/) a try. Doing so you can include the field in your criteria query. But you have to try if you cann use counts in the annotation

Comment: Unfortunatly, I can't use @Formula, this value is based on the connected user, and Formula can not take any parameter

Comment: You can try the Hibernate specific non-portable `@Formula` or create a database view  which can be mapped to your existing entity via JPA `@SecondaryTable`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53176186/hibernate-relation-with-aggregation/53177583#53177583

Answer (score 0):

I managed to implement a workaround using Alan idea (that didn't exactly matched what I wanted, since my value depends on the connected user).

That is not an ideal solution, but I created a view with the slideshow columns + `employee_id` + the calculated `seen`field.

```
create view employee_slideshow as
(select s.*, e.id as employee_id, (select COUNT(ss.slideshow_id) > 0 from seen_slideshow ss where ss.slideshow_id = s.id and ss.employee_id = e.id) as seen
from slideshow s, employee e
group by s.id, e.id)
```

This view can be paginated, sorted and filtered by the employee.

Then, I created an entity that matches this view, with its repository :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee_slideshow")
public class EmployeeSlideshow {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    // and the other slideshow fields

    private boolean seen;

    private String employeeId;
}
```

That is not what I expected from Spring JPA, but with a small volumetry, that will be okay.